# box-shadow inset only on one side?

Tags: html, css

So I´m currently trying to get my hero section image to blur towards the bottom with thise classes:

```
.hero-section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("../../assets/Images/governance.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 40px #232323 inset;
  margin-bottom: 10rem;
}
```

How would I have to change the box shadow so it only blurs on the bottom side, any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: Seems like you want a gradient rather than a box shadow.

Comment: Here's a quick demo for a regular *soft-button*. Notice the coma delimited double inset: `<div style="border-radius: 5px; background-color: silver; color: black; box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px 1px white, inset -1px -1px 2px 1px black; padding: 0.125rem 1rem">button</div>`. Just for fun...

Answer (score 1):

The first 2 values you pass in are for the X, Y coordinates. So you if you want for example inset along the bottom you would use -1px on the Y axis.

```js
    box-shadow: -1px 0 3px 3px black inset;
```

You would do a positive value on the y Axis for the top.
A Negative value on the X axis for Left and positive on the right.

Comment: Worked out now! 
Had to add a px value for the third attribute like so:
box-shadow: 0px -30px 30px 0px #232323 inset;

Comment: I will update the answer to include. Thanks!